# Nginx cors configuration for 2 sub-domains with separate ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx, cors, nginx-config

I have two apps running on my server.

1. A react app on port 4512 (locally on HTTP) and 5512 (on https). Can be accessed on https://merchant.abc.com:5512
2. A node js (express) API on port 4511 (locally on http) and 5511 (on https) served on https://ce.abc.com:5511

Initially, I was using a wildcard SSL certificate for both sub-domains, and nodejs was taking care of CORS. But we were then required to use separate SSL certificates for both domains. When I used separate SSL certificates, Nginx started to deny cors requests (I was able to use API using postman).

I then read about Nginx cors options on some posts here and came up with the following Nginx settings

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
# Vendor API
server {
    listen 5511  ssl;
    ssl_certificate /ssl/ssl-bundle-api.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/ssl-api.key;

    location /{
        include /etc/nginx/shared/allow-cors;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:4511;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    }
}

# Retailer app
server {
    listen 5512  ssl;
    ssl_certificate /ssl/ssl-bundle-react.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/ssl-react.key;

    location /{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4512;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/shared/allow-cors

```
if ($request_method = "OPTIONS") {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'DELETE,GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT' always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,X-Token-Auth,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000 always;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8' always;
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0 always;

    return 204;
}

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'DELETE,GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT' always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,X-Token-Auth,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With' always;
```

I then removed the cors settings from the nodejs API. This seemed to fix the issue on my aws ec2 ubuntu 18.04 instance completely. But when I deploy this code on the client's on-premise server (created using image of my ec2 instance) it again has issues. On Firefox it seems like the pre-flight check gets the expected 204, but then I don't see any POST request being sent.
[image]

On Chrome I see a successful pre-flight check with 204. I also see the actual POST request in chrome, but with a `(failed) net::ERR_FAILED` status.
[image]
[image]
Can somebody please help be resolving this.

Comment: The client's server is behind its own firewall (probably cisco). Is it possible that the firewall is the issue?

Comment: You should also check the console - not only the Network tab. Console usually contains a more verbose error message.